# In React, is there a way to have a toggle switch, onChange or onClick, switch to either the first function (thirtyDays) or the second function (year)?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to allow the user to select what will display via a toggle switch.  For example, I have two functions:  thirtyDays & year.  Either onChange or onClick, I would like for the user to be able to switch which function is called. Is there a way to do this?  Here is my code for the ToggleButton component:

```
thirtyDays = (props) => {
    console.log("the past 30 days of transactions");
    var now = new Date();
    now.setDate(now.getDate() - 30);
  }

  year = (props) => {
    console.log("year of transactions");
   var now = new Date();
   now.setDate(now.getDate() - 365);
  }

  render() {

    return (
 <label className="switch">
        {
          <>
            {" "}
            <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn" />
            <div type="button" className="slider round">
              <span className="on">Year</span>
              <span className="off">30 Days</span>
            </div>
          </>
        }
      </label>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my css:

```
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 175px;
  height: 50px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: forestgreen;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 50px;
  width:50px;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2ab934;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgb(2, 61, 2);
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(100px);
  transform: translateX(100px);
} 

/*------ ADDED CSS ---------*/
 .on
{
  display: none;
}

.off, .on
{
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

input:checked+ .slider .on
{display: block;}

input:checked + .slider .off
{display: none;} 

/*--------- END --------*/

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;}
```

Here is my codesandbox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-rgb-y62rm?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

You can decide about function which you call checking state of your checkbox inside another function. Example:

```js
  const changePeriod = (e) => {
    if ( console.log( e.target.checked ) ) {
      year( /* your params */ )
    } else {
      thirtyDays( /* your params */ )
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="checkbox" onChange={ changePeriod }/>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to maintain the toggle state in your component. Or, if you're willing to use a plugin, you could try react-switch.

Here's a working example - https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-water-l4pr6